# Making an Object Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hey Everyone I am trying to make Neuron as an Object that is a list of 3 doubles
after declaration, however when I try to write the recall method, it says • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Double]’ with actual type ‘Neuron’, anyone knows where the problem is thanks in advance

```
-- simple neuron
data Neuron = Neuron [Double]
      deriving (Read,Show)

recall :: Neuron -> [Double] -> Double
recall ws xs = y
 where y = sum (zipWith (*) ws (-1:xs))
```

Comment: Your `Neuron` is not a list, it contains a list. Try `recall (Neuron ws) xs = ...`

Comment: If it should be 3 doubles (no more, and no less) you probably should use tuple `(Double, Double, Double)`

Comment: @user28434 actually then it should be `data Neuron = Neuron !Double !Double !Double`, probably. But, why _would_ it be always exactly 3?

Comment: @leftaroundabout There are valid reasons to make a newtype wrapper around a tuple, especially if the data are naturally represented as a tuple as I believe is the case here. But then it should be a newtype wrapper and not a data wrapper.

Comment: @AndrewRay if anything, it should be a newtype around something like [`V3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.21.3/docs/Linear-V3.html).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Potentially, but some people are less comfortable introducing external dependencies and I don't want to assume people want to use external packages without them being mentioned. And ultimately, this is tangential to OP's question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, just realised that `recall` is just a scalar product of two vectors (where first element of the second one is fixed `-1`)

Answer (score 2):

`Neuron` is not the same thing as `[Double]`; it is instead a wrapper around `[Double]`. Thus you must *unwrap* the value before you can use it like a list:

```
recall :: Neuron -> [Double] -> Double
recall (Neuron ws) xs = y
    where y = sum (zipWith (*) ws (-1:xs))
```

Though I have another issue with your code. In this example, since you know that a `Neuron` must wrap a list of specifically 3 `Double`s, you should enforce that with the type system, instead defining `Neuron` as:

```
newtype Neuron = Neuron (Double, Double, Double)
    deriving (Read, Show)

recall :: Neuron -> [Double] -> Double
recall (Neuron (w1, w2, w3)) xs = y (xs ++ repeat 0)
    where y (x2:x3:_) = w1 * (-1) + w2 * x2 + w3 * x3
```

Yes, you lose out on using `zipWith` and `sum`, but that's really just obscuring a simpler underlying calculation. There's no need to use generic functions when only one specific case will ever be used.

Note also the use of `newtype` instead of `data`. `newtype` gives you potentially more performant derived implementations of `Read` and `Show` and also provides access to advanced tools like Generalized Newtype Deriving, which you may not care about now, but later may be very useful. In general, using `newtype` instead of `data` for datatypes that just wrap another datatype is a good habit to get into.

In a comment, @leftroundabout also mentions that if the data do not naturally form a tuple or vector, you should not wrap a tuple, in which case the code would look like this:

```
data Neuron = Neuron { property1 :: Double
                     , property2 :: Double
                     , property3 :: Double
                     } deriving (Read, Show)

recall :: Neuron -> [Double] -> Double
recall (Neuron w1 w2 w3) xs = y (xs ++ repeat 0)
    where y (x2:x3:_) = w1 * (-1) + w2 * x2 + w3 * x3
```